# Ms Access VBA too fast to refresh excel listobjects

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Ms Access to refresh some excel tables(list objects)
If I go into my vba and hit f8 and step through the code it works perfectly but when I just try and run the code fails at refreshing the excel tables(the excel tables have background refresh off).

Below is the code snippet which I cant seem to get it to work and im not sure if I need to use a wait function or multiple refresh all.

```
Public Function RunMyQuery()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim ZDate As Date
    Dim dd, mm, yyyy As String
    Dim TStart, TEnd, TElapsed As Single

   'Open excel and refresh tables linked to access
    LogText = "Refresh Excel Tables"
    UpdateProgressLog LogFile, LogText, TElapsed

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("Excel file location.xlsb")
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
                TStart = Timer
                lo.QueryTable.Refresh False
                'lo.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                TEnd = Timer
                TElapsed = Format(TEnd - TStart, "Fixed")
                LogText = lo
                UpdateProgressLog LogFile, LogText, TElapsed
                TElapsed = 0
            Next lo
        Next ws
```

The UpdateProgressLog and Timer stuff all relates to a txt file that logs every step so I can see where it fails

Comment: The `Refresh()` method returns a boolean. Build your logic around it. Also remove the brackets around `False`.

Comment: Sorry Kostas K I removed brackets but not sure what yo mean by building the logic around it. sorry im not that good at vba which probably shows in my code!

Comment: The code is fine. :) You can add an `If` condition in your loop to force it wait the refresh operation.  `If lo.QueryTable.Refresh(False) Then ...` and then do the rest or throw an error if the method returns false.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean kostas sorry my vba isnt that good and struggling to work it out? are you anle to provide a quick example thanks